# How to self revoke token via vault api?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

When i try to revoke a self token using api method i'm getting permission denied error

```
curl -H "X-Vault-Token: s.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYY" -X GET $VAULT_ADDR/v1/auth/token/revoke-self
{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]}
```

But if i login using same token and try via cli it is working as expected

```
$ vault token revoke -self
Success! Revoked token (if it existed)
```

Is it working as expected? or am i trying to use in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "POST" request instead of the "GET" one:

```
curl -H "X-Vault-Token: s.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYY" -X POST $VAULT_ADDR/v1/auth/token/revoke-self
```